# "Add New Item" to the currently active project directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there an option somewhere in Visual Studio 2008, that when you "Add new item" he defaults the chosen save location in the window that pops up, to the directory of the currently active project ?

For now, it just saves it to previous saved file location (usually the last project worked on).

Comment: The only option I know of is the probjects location setting under projects and solutions in the options dialog.

Comment: Yes, I know of that one. Unfortunatelly, it doesn't quite solve this problem. Why is this bugging me? Because I hate not paying attention at that, and then finding out I saved a lot of source files, for example, in a previous project directory. Annoying ...